# Clear h:inputText and h:selectOneMenu value on page refresh

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

I have a Facelets page with two `<h:inputText>` text fields and one `<h:selectOneMenu>` dropdown field. When I refresh my page, then the values that are entered in text fields should be cleared and dropdown should be reset to its default selection. This is not happening. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Where do you get the values for these input text fields from? I would guess your bean is on session scope or something, so that values are retained.

Comment: ofcourse these values are user given input.let say when user open my page and write a value in first text field , now without submission if he refresh the page then input fileds should be clear again.AND i tried request scope as well but it didn't work IN THIS CASE

Answer (score 1):

Modern webbrowsers will autocomplete input fields by default or by configuration. If you'd like to prevent this browser specific behaviour, then you need to add `autocomplete="off"` to the individual input fields.

```
<h:inputText ... autocomplete="off" />
<h:inputText ... autocomplete="off" />
<h:selectOneMenu ... autocomplete="off" />
```

#### See also:

- [W3 Web Forms 2.0 specification - `autocomplete` attribute](http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#the-autocomplete)

Comment: I have tried this but this is another thing.The thing I am telling is to refresh/reset the view of specific component on page refresh